Can I perform an ANOVA on the outcomes of regression?
I was told that it's not usual practice to run an ANOVA off of the slopes and intercepts obtained from a regression.
I made "retinotopy" models for each point on the surface of the cortex, and removed all models which did not reach an $R^2$ of $0.15$. Each vertex of the surface of the cortex has a model created, by correlating the location of stimulus and the amplitude of fMRI signal. The technique is known as retinotopic mapping. Retinotopic mapping estimates population receptive fields (pRFs), which are the locations in the visual field that a particular area of the brain responds to. We need to remove low $R^2$ values, because if a model has low $R^2$, that area of the surface probably isn't capturing an area of the visual field which was activated by my stimulus during the fMRI scan.
Each model has the attributes "Eccentricity" and "pRF size". Eccentricity is a measure of the distance from the center of gaze to the location of the pRF. In early visual cortex (V1, V2, and V3) the very back of the cortex has low eccentricity, and eccentricity is higher closer to the front of the brain. An eccentricity of $7$ indicates that the receptive field is $7$ degrees away from from the center of gaze. A pRF size of $2$ means that the radius of the receptive field is $2$ degrees. It is well established that as eccentricity increases (pRFs are further from the center of gaze), pRF size increases, and that this is a linear relationship (at least, within the area of the visual field which I stimulated). It is also well-established that the linear relationship is less steep in the primary visual cortex ($V1$), steeper in $V2$, and even steeper in $V3$.
I have a patient group and a control group. My patient group lost one eye in childhood. I'm interested in how this effects linear relationship of pRF size and eccentricity. I'm interested in whether this change in linear relationship is different in the three ROI's of the early visual cortex, and whether this effect is larger based on hemisphere. Hemisphere is defined relative to the removed eye for the patient group, and relative to the dominant eye for the control group.
I made linear regression models to look at the rate at which pRF size increases as eccentricity increases. Each participant has $6$ different linear models, representing $3$ ROIs X $2$ Hemispheres, each based on about $8'000$ retinotopy models. I have $12$ participants, so across subjects, across ROIs, there are about $100'000$ retinotopy models, and $72$ linear regression models.
I'm interested in comparing the slopes and the intercepts of the eccentricity-pRF size linear regressions between groups, and within hemispheres, and within $3$ visual regions, and looking at the interactions. When I run the ANOVA, the results look quite reasonable, and match the visualizations created from the data.
Is it bad practice to run an ANOVA off of regression? To me it seems reasonable, but a professor who is much better-versed in stats than I am disagreed with me. He said that doing an ANOVA on the models created by linear regression is never done because you're ignoring too much variance. My feeling was that running an ANOVA on linear regression outcomes is not inherently that different from running an ANOVA on medians/means. In both cases you're summarizing certain tendencies of the behavior of the data.
The following is my Greenhouse-Geyser corrected ANOVA table for the Eccentricity-pRF size slope.



Effect
df
MSE
F
ges
p value




Group
1, 10
.002
.47
.034
.508


ROI
1.25, 12.47
0
67.98
.452
<.001


Group:ROI
1.25, 12.47
0
1.27
.015
.293


hemisphere
1, 10
0
2.58
.016
.139


Group:hemisphere
1, 10
0
16.16
.093
.002


ROI:hemisphere
1.54, 15.36
0
6.35
.043
.014


Group:ROI:hemisphere
1.54, 15.36
0
.6
.004
.520



It shows the expected difference in ROI, and that there are group differences in slope, based on hemisphere. post hoc tests show that the patient group has steeper linear models in the hemisphere contralateral to the remaining eye, and the control group has steeper in the hemisphere ipsilateral to their dominant eye.

Please edit the question with more details about the measurements you are modeling and how "Eccentricity" and "pRF size" enter into the models. Are they predictors or outcomes? If predictors, what are they predicting? Also, usual $R^2$ values are limited to [0,1]; it's not clear how you got values of 15. Furthermore, it's bad practice to remove results that seem "insignifcant" as it can lead to bias. Finally, please be specific in the question about what you want to compare "between groups, and within hemispheres, and within 3 visual regions" and the interactions you want to investigate.

I agree with everything @EdM has already mentioned. I think it would also help to show the exact models you have estimated so it is clear what exactly you did and why you believe it may be problematic.

Your professor might be getting at the underlying variances of the 72 slope estimates, for which you do have information. In linear models (of which ANOVA is one example) you typically want to weight observations inversely to the their variances. Simply jumping ahead to ANOVA on your slope estimates treats each slope as equally reliable. With over 1000 pRFs contributing on average to each regression, however, I suspect that the variances of the slope estimates are fairly small so that might not be a problem.
I am, however, a little worried how you use linear regression within each of the ROIs to get the slopes, in two respects.
First, as I understand the way that pRF eccentricity and size are calculated (see, for example, Neuroimage. 2021 Dec 1; 244: 118609), it seems that the modeling of the combination of fMRI signal and stimulus characteristics to estimate those pRF characteristics could lead to substantial variance in estimates of both eccentricity and size. Standard linear regression assumes that the "independent" variable (evidently eccentricity here) is known exactly (or at least more precisely than the "dependent" variable). Is that the case here?
Second, and maybe more important, it's not clear how you are handling the intercepts of the size-eccentricity regressions. If they are different from 0 (is there really 0 size for a pRF at the center of the visual field?) and differ among ROI then it's not clear how one might properly interpret the slopes.
This might better be handled with a combined mixed regression model of size as a function of eccentricity, instead of starting with the results of 72 separate regressions. You would include interaction terms involving Group, hemisphere and ROI to see how both intercepts and slopes of the size-eccentricity association change with those variables, while treating participant as a random effect to try to account for intra-individual correlations. You might discuss that approach with your professor.

Absolutely, there's a difference in eccentricity, pRF size estimates depending on the stimulus configuration that you use, and the rate of sampling. However, as each participant was scanned using the same protocol, this shouldn't be too problematic.
There definitely isn't a 0 intercept, it's technically impossible for a pRF to have a size of 0. The intercept is usually between 0.1 and 0.15 degrees large, but . Actually, when running an ANOVA on the intercepts we found that

@MattM-D running separate ANOVAs on intercepts and slopes isn't a good idea, as there will almost certainly be correlations between intercepts and slopes in a linear model. Those correlations might be another source of (co)variance that troubles your professor. Separate ANOVAs won't account for that. That's another reason to consider a mixed model that allows for interactions between the size-eccentricity association and your predictors of interest. That will give you more reliable information on both slopes and intercepts while respecting their correlations.

Thanks for the help. Off of your recommendation, I've made a mixed effects model (Eccentricity* Group * hemisphere * ROI) that looks like it's essentially giving the same information as was derived separately from the intercept and slope ANOVA, although I'm unsure of how to assess significance. I read on another site that Markov Chains assess the significance of mixed linear models, would you say that that's the best way to assess significance?

@MattM-D that's a complicated issue a bit out of my comfort zone. This page has extensive discussion; yes, MCMC is one favored approach. I haven't thought this through completely, but it's also possible that you could use generalized least squares, which allows for correlation structures other than the sphericity assumed by the mixed model. Generalized least squares is more akin to the ANOVA approach (and associated tests) that you started with. Discuss with your professor.
